# Problème avec mon API en python

Tags: api

Well, I am a work-study student and I am asked to create an API to retrieve data from their software.
(I don't know much about API I discovered with this project, so please don't judge my stupid mistakes).

The documentation : https://api.sellsy.fr/documentation/methodes

```
try:
    infos = client.api(method='Client.getList', params={
        'search'={
            'periodecreated_start'={int(1577836800)}
        }
    })
except sellsy_api.SellsyAuthenticateError as e: 
    print('Authentication failed ! Details : {}'.format(e))
except sellsy_api.SellsyError as e: 
    print(e)
```

I am getting this error:

```
infos = client.api(method='Client.getList', params={
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

Here I am trying to get out the list of clients since 01/01/2020.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Please find a more descriptive title in english. Thank you. (It will help you get views and therefore useful answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`params={....}` is a keyword argument, sending presumably a dictionary to the method. The dictionary `{'search':...}` would be okay; `{'search'=...}` is not a valid dict syntax. Instead, it gets interpreted as a *set*, with a single value, the value of the expression `'search'=...`; but that is not a grammatical expression in Python. The error is repeated with `{'periodecreated_start'=...}`.

Comment: Somethink like this ?

`try:
    infos = client.api('Client.getList',{
        'search':{
        'periodecreated_start':{int(1577836800)}
        }
    })`

Answer (score 0):

params={....} is a keyword argument, sending presumably a dictionary to the method. The dictionary {'search':...} would be okay; {'search'=...} is not a valid dict syntax. Instead, it gets interpreted as a set, with a single value, the value of the expression 'search'=...; but that is not a grammatical expression in Python. The error is repeated with {'periodecreated_start'=...}....